# Must we have to download the remote file before using AirDrop?

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop

I am sending the remote file (for example: image file, pdf file ... ) to Airdrop.
I have only the direct link of this file : http://example.com/xxx/png.
Currently, I am doing something like below code

```
NSString *filePath = self downloadFileFromServerWithURL
NSURL *urlFilePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSArray *Items     = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:indexPath.row],
                                          urlFilePath,nil];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:Items applicationActivities:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:xxx, yyy,nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So, my question is, how can I share the remote file with Airdrop without downloading it before?
I show a lot of iOS softwares can do that, like DropBox

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you should look into using a subclass of [UIActivityItemProvider](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemProvider_Class/) which will let you asynchronously get/generate the actual item to be shared. The [AirDrop sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html) has an example of this.